Installation error when installing parrot os, I get the following screen
Tipos de traducción
Traducción de texto
Texto original
764 / 5.000
Resultados de traducción
Resultado de traducción
When I go to install parrot os from a bootable pen, when it starts up it shows me the following message, does anyone know what is wrong?
GNU GRUB version 2.06-13+parrot5 Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. for the first word , TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device os file completion grub>
(when I press TAB it tells me the following) authenticate boot break clear configfile continue export extract_entries:configfile extract_entries_source gettext insmod is menuentry net_add_addr net_add_dns net_add_route net_bootp net_bootp6 net_del_addr net_del_dns net_del.....
I would greatly appreciate any help, greetings, I tried to upload a screenshot but it won't let me and neither will lowering the resolution of the image.
